# NFA and DFA implementation

Tags: f#, state-machine

Can you review my F# code and point out some insights about it?

What I want to know, in order of relevance:

- Avoid so much common code between DFA and NFA. I want to make something more generic, there is much code in common there.
- Make it more F# idiomatic

Performance is not a concern. Readability is.

```
module DFA =
    type DeterministicFiniteAutomaton = {
        InitialState: string
        FinalStates: Set<string>
        Transitions: Map<string * char, string>
    }

    let private nextState (symbol:char) (state:string) (transitions:Map<string * char, string>) =
        transitions |> Map.tryFind (state, symbol)

    let rec private haltState (input:string) (index:int) (state:string) (transitions:Map<string * char, string>) =
        match index with
        | i when i = input.Length -> state
        | _ ->
            match nextState input.[index] state transitions with
            | None -> null
            | Some state -> haltState input (index+1) state transitions

    let accepts (input:string) (dfa:DeterministicFiniteAutomaton) =
        dfa.FinalStates |> Set.contains (haltState input 0 dfa.InitialState dfa.Transitions)

module NFA =
    type NondeterministicFiniteAutomaton = {
        InitialState: string
        FinalStates: Set<string>
        Transitions: Map<string * char, string List>
    }

    let private nextState (symbol:char) (state:string) (transitions:Map<string * char, string List>) =
        transitions |> Map.tryFind (state, symbol)

    let rec private haltStates (input:string) (index:int) (state:string) (transitions:Map<string * char, string List>) =
        match index with
        | i when i = input.Length -> Seq.singleton state
        | _ ->
            match nextState input.[index] state transitions with
            | None -> Seq.empty
            | Some states ->
                states |> Seq.collect (fun state ->
                    haltStates input (index+1) state transitions)

    let accepts (input:string) (nfa:NondeterministicFiniteAutomaton) =
        haltStates input 0 nfa.InitialState nfa.Transitions
        |> Set.ofSeq
        |> Set.intersect nfa.FinalStates
        |> Set.count > 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look shows the only difference with your `FiniteAutomaton` types is that the transition either takes a `string` or `string List`.  So genericize it!

```
type FiniteAutomaton<'a> = {
    InitialState: string
    FinalStates: Set<string>
    Transitions: Map<string * char, 'a>
}
type DeterministicFiniteAutomaton = FiniteAutomaton<string>
type NondeterministicFiniteAutomaton = FiniteAutomaton<string List>
```

The rest pretty much falls in place:

```
let private nextState symbol state fa =
    fa.Transitions |> Map.tryFind (state, symbol)

let rec private haltState (input:string) index state fa =
    match index with
    | i when i = input.Length -> state
    | _ ->
        match nextState input.[index] state fa with
        | None -> null
        | Some state -> haltState input (index+1) state fa

let accepts input fa =
    fa.FinalStates |> Set.contains (haltState input 0 fa.InitialState fa)
```

I try to remove as much type annotations as possible.  Just let F#'s type inference do its magic. Also, it was convenient to pass around the `fa` instead of `fa.Transitions`.  Finally, the code compiles, but I have no idea if it works.

**Edit:**

If you want to be totaly generic you can do this:

```
type FiniteAutomaton<'STATE, 'TOKEN when 'STATE:comparison and 'TOKEN:comparison> = {
    InitialState: 'STATE
    FinalStates: Set<'STATE>
    Transitions: Map<'STATE * 'TOKEN, 'STATE List>
}
```

Also `'STATE` should be a `'TOKEN List`.

Comment: Your code looks nice, but there is a problem: `let private nextState symbol state fa` wants a `string` for parameter `state`, so it will infer that  `'a` is `string` in `haltState` and `accepts` too. Even if I put some type annotations in `haltState` and `accepts`, the `nextState` function will infer `string` for `state`.

Comment: See: https://gist.github.com/ihavenonickname/cb0dfd902ee23b6efc605120c1390dec

Comment: Say me what do you think about my idea: Keep only the code of my old NFA module, and when it is a DFA then all keys in `Transitions` map will all point to lists with 1 element each (thus it's deterministic).

Comment: Yes, a one element list would work for deterministic FA.  Also you can get extra generic. See above.